# linalg.spsolve and linalg.cg giving different solutions?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, solver

I'm sure there the answer is obvious but I'm unsure as to why these two solvers are giving different solutions for the same two inputs?

```
# create sparse matrix with 25% non-zeros
A = sparse.random(6, 6, density = 0.6)
plt.spy(A)
plt.show()
print("Sparse matrix C: \n", A)

# create randomised RHS Vector b
b = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(6), p=[1/2, 1/2])
print("Vector B is: \n", b)

# solve
X = sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b)
print("Solution vector for matrix S is: \n", X)

X1 = sparse.linalg.cg(A, b, x0 = None, tol = 1e-05)
print("Solution vector for matrix S is: \n", X1)
```

[the two solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StzvH.jpg)

Comment: Your question would be more readable if you included the solutions directly rather than as an image.

Comment: Which solution looks right, and why?

Comment: `cg` says `A must represent a hermitian, positive definite matrix`.  I suspect the random array doesn't qualify.  Most of the other iterative methods, without such a constraint, appear to work.

Comment: A real symetric matrix works in `cg`.